# GitHub actions sending artifacts by email

Tags: yaml, github-actions, workflow, pipeline, cicd

Can anyone see why my workflow file is receiving error - 'Run dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read'.

I can see in GitHub that the artifact is saved successfully, but cannot seem to add this to the email unfortunately.

Workflow file is as follows:

```
name: Cypress Tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  Cypress-Test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout GitCode
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
      - name: Run Cypress Test
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4
        with:
          command: npx cypress run
          browser: chrome

      - name: Store Cypress Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-results
          path: |
            cypress/screenshots/
            cypress/videos/
            cypress/reports/
  Send-Email:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: Cypress-Test
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: Checkout GitCode
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download Cypress artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: cypress-results
          path: cypress-results

      - name: Send email with Cypress artifacts
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
        with:
          server_address: smtp.gmail.com
          server_port: 465
          username: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
          subject: "Cypress test results for ${{ github.repository }} ${{ github.sha }}"
          from: Test Suite
          body: |
            Hi,
            The Cypress test workflow for ${{ github.repository }} ${{ github.sha }} has completed.
            Please find the Cypress artifacts attached to this email.
            Regards,
            abc
          to: abc@gmail.com
          attachments: |
            ./cypress-results/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I have observed same issue and was able to send html report not entire folder using .html at the end. For your case you can try ./cypress-results/*.html